# Is there a workaround for ISP NAT blocking docker containers internet access?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, docker, nat, ubuntu-20.04

All my containers have no internet access when using the **"bridge"** docker network that's created by default. However, using the **"host"** network, there's internet access.

I called my new ISP for network connectivity problems with docker containers, and they answered me that their "politics" currently not allow this, and the use of double NAT is whats throwing my containers' internet access under the bus.

Is there any way to bypass this? I've been reading the use of a DMZ or Upnp protocol can help you with this problem, which I've not tried yet.

Also read in another article that using a second router might help, I'm being delivered a new router this week so I've yet to try this.

I haven't asked my ISP if they provide the "reserved public ip" service yet.

Is there anything else that I can try to get this working?

Comment: I don't have much experience with docker but it sounds like you have a carrier grade NAT, but this shouldn't prevent the containers from accessing the internet (only the other way around would be a problem since port forward is not possible on a double NAT if the ISP doesn't play along).

Comment: Most residential service agreements with ISP's (in the US at least) include clauses about not supporting hosting servers, limited inbound traffic, etc. It is standard practice (and often hidden in legal mumbo-jumbo). In general, you would need a commercial account (usually 2-5 times more expensive) with a static public IP address, then handle the routing yourself. The workaround from SOME ISP's is to get a bridged modem and use your own router, but some ISP's do not support this configuration. The fact these are docker containers is not relevant, they are just network hosts.

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: Thanks for you comments, I'll see through the article. I will also consider changing my ISP.